# git: removing strange remote branch

Tags: git, branch

I've started work with a messy repository: the task is to remove all useless, merged-in branches. When I list the remote branches, I can see:

```
remotes/origin/xx12
remotes/origin/xx13
remotes/origin/remotes/origin/xx14
```

I can run

```
git push origin :xx12
git push origin :xx13
```

to remove `xx12` and `xx13`. But I don't know how can I remove `xx14` which has strange path `remotes/origin/remotes/origin`. I don't know how it was done and why, but I'd like to remove it safely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the remote branch is "remotes/origin/xx14". So, you can remove it with its full name as you do for the others. Try:

```
git push origin :remotes/origin/xx14
```